# Selecting Vertical Edges with Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a node setup that converts hair cards into curve hair with geometry nodes, the idea is to use the vertical edges as a guide for sampling new curves around it, after searching i've found a way to select the boundary loop using these nodes setup

[image]

but the issue is, that it leaves theses edges on top and bottom

[image]

There's any better way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: What's a hair card? I think you should edit the question and include some images of its geometry. You should also define the problem a bit more. For example - are those hair cards all the same, or do they differ, if so how?..

Comment: .. and are the card meshes aligned to their own object-space? (Are local x,y,z consistently along the card's edges?)

Comment: Depending on how the mesh was created there is a good chance that the face corners are all in the same ordering (i.e. the numbers you get from node `Face of Corner` output `Index in Face`). You can easily check by using the `Triangulate` node in mode `Fixed`: all triangulation edges should be "parallel"). If that´s the case, it is possible to separate "vertical" edges from "horizontal" ones, even if the mesh is arbitrarily deformed. But I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for(?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately your question is everything else than crystal clear, but i try to answer although i doubt that you meant that:

[image]

I just compare the z-positions of each edge, and if they are not the same, i delete them. Hope it helps.